# navigationbar set background image not working in ios6

Tags: ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

There is a problem during set image in `NavigationBar` in `ios6`

Here is my code

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Its not working, what can I do?

This code is written inside `viewDidLoad` , is that right or wrong?

Comment: Is right that, but all depends if self.navigationController.navigationBar was found. Check for nil.

Answer (score 2):

try this

your code is right.

If you dont find the UINavigationBar on the next class means , it does not have a navigation controller, so before pushing it add a UINavigationController to your next view.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarBG.png"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```